# Problem with ecryptfs and rsync on arch

Tags: arch-linux, encryption

I'm trying to encrypt my home directory with `ecryptfs-migrate-home`.

When I try to run this command, I get the following error message:

```
ERROR: please install the rsync package.
```

But the `rsync` package *is* installed via pacman from the standard repos. It is available in shell by calling `$ rsync`.

- I've tried to add to `PATH` the `rsync` executable for both users (the user that I use to execute `ecryptfs-migrate-home` and the final user whose home I want to encrypt).
- I've already tried to reinstall all packages but always I got the same error.

Comment: Your comment about adjusting `$PATH` seems to imply that you've installed `rsync` in a non-standard place. Where is it installed, and how did you adjust `$PATH`?

Comment: I installed 3 PCs today and got the problem on one of them. The other two just worked fine. Do you have a solution? I installed rsync via pacman from the standard repos. It is available in shell.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot answer but the problem is simple: tl;dr: "pacman -S which" Install the which command. the migrate script uses it to check whether rsync is installed. If it is unavailable, the check fails.